# Object is not callable

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8

I make this condition:

```
if ((liste_mois[0]==3) or (liste_mois[0]==6) (liste_mois[0]==9) or (liste_mois[0]==12))
```

i got: TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Comment: You missed a or in between. Closing as typo.

Comment: `(liste_mois[0]==6) (liste_mois[0]==9)` <- there. Put an `or` between those two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed an "or" in between.

Answer (score 1):

You've got:

> TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

just because you're doing something like that:

```
(liste_mois[0]==6) (liste_mois[0]==9)
```

which could be represented as, let's say:

```
(True) (False)
```

and going further:

```
(True)()
```

so in your statement you treat boolean value `(liste_mois[0]==6)` as a function, because you're trying to invoke it. And because boolean value is not callable, that's the reason you see this error.

Similar example to `(liste_mois[0]==6) (liste_mois[0]==9)` could be:

```
def something():
    pass

(something)() # <-- this
```

So solution for you will be to put `or` in your `if` condition, so:

```
if ((liste_mois[0]==3) or (liste_mois[0]==6) or (liste_mois[0]==9) or (liste_mois[0]==12))
```

and I think that is what you want.